# Is this a LINQ lazy loading problem?

Tags: linq

Something very strange is happening in my program:

I make this query **agt.DefaultNr == 1** on a collection and get 3 items as Result:

```
IEnumerable<Agent> favAgents =
            from agt in builtAgents where agt.DefaultNr == 1 select agt;
```

For every item I set the **DefaultNr = 0**

```
foreach (Agent noFavAgt in favAgents)
{
    noFavAgt.DefaultNr = 0;
}
```

I do another query but for some reason my favAgents collection is empty now!

```
IEnumerable<Agent> smallAgents = (from agt in favAgents
    where agt.tempResultCount < 30
    orderby agt.tempResultCount descending
    select agt);
```

What is going on here?

Is this a LINQ lazy loading problem?

Looks like there will be some kind of re-query after I set all items = 0 because I my collection is empty!

Comment: What is the relation between the two queries and why should it return a value. You filter on the `tempResultCount` property in the second query while change the `DefaultNr` property in the first query. Are you talking about LINQ to Objects (LINQ over in-memory collections) or some sort of O/RM tool (such as LINQ to SQL)?

Comment: Are you sure it's the collection that's empty and not just that nothing matches your second query's criteria?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not *lazy loading*, it's *deferred execution*. When you define your initial enumerable, you're defining a *query*, not a *collection*. You're correct that it's performing a requery; every time you iterate over `favAgents`, it will execute the query that you defined. If you want to create a list based off of that query that doesn't change, add `ToList()`.

```
var favAgents = 
    (from agt in builtAgents where agt.DefaultNr == 1 select agt).ToList();
```

Doing this will create a list in memory and cache the results of the query at that point in time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your `favAgents` collection will be empty now - you've "turned off" the bit in each element of it that made it match the query! If you iterate over `favAgents` twice, it will execute the query twice. `favAgents` represents the query itself, *not* the results.

If you want to preserve one particular set of results, use `ToList` or something similar:

```
favAgents = favAgents.ToList();
```

That will *materialize* the query - perform it once and then remember the results in a list, basically. `ToArray` would have the same effect, but store the results in an array instead.